# Set an ipython widget value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter

Say that there is a ipywidget created in IPython notebook, like so:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
i = widgets.IntText()
```

Is there a way to set the value from Javascript? I suspect that I'll need to know some comm id of the widget. Or is there a better way to have a variable in Python that gets set from Javascript?

The use case is that I want to send a mouse click position (gotten via Javascript) position back to Python.

Comment: JavaScript running where? Node.js? A web browser?

Comment: IPython notebooks run with a frontend in the browser, and a backend on the server. I'm looking for a way for Javascript in the browser to set the value of the traitlet so that the value can be accessed in Python on the server.

Comment: @Quant Ok, but I am going to need a link or more information. Thanks!

Comment: @DougBlank could not add multi-line code snippet in the comment. I replied below with a short example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to SylvainCorlay and jasongrout on ipython gitter, they were able to talk me through this:

```
clicked = function (evt, x_model, y_model) {
    var e = evt.srcElement.farthestViewportElement || evt.target;
    var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
    var y = evt.clientY - dim.top;
    var manager = IPython.WidgetManager._managers[0];
    var model_prom = manager.get_model(x_model);
    model_prom.then(function(model) {
        model.set('value', Math.round(x));
        model.save_changes();
    });
    model_prom = manager.get_model(y_model);
    model_prom.then(function(model) {
        model.set('value', Math.round(y));
        model.save_changes();
    });
};
```

Where onclick is called with the event, and the Python x.model_id and y.model_id.

Comment: And how exactly I get x_model and y_model variables passed to the function?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind widget models on the JavaScript side using the ipython `jslink` widget.

```
from ipywidgets import IntText, IntSlider, jslink
from IPython.display import display

text, slider = IntText(), IntSlider()
link = jslink((text, 'value'), (slider, 'value'))
display(text, slider)
```

If you want a pure JavaScript solution, you can address the widget model from the widget manager using the widget id.

Comment: What does the Javascript side look like?

Comment: The value must be set on the widget backbone model. `model.set('value', 17);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this nootebook if you can install jupyter proxy server

https://github.com/gbrault/jpjwidgets